# Scala: Return multiple data types from function

Tags: scala

This is somewhat of a theoretical question but something I might want to do.  Is it possible to return multiple data data types from a Scala function but limit the types that are allowed?  I know I can return one type by specifying it, or I can essentially allow any data type by not specifying the return type, but I would like to return 1 of 3 particular data types to preserve a little bit of type safety.  Is there a way to write an 'or' in the return type like:

```
def myFunc(input:String): [Int || String] = { ...}
```

The main context for this is trying to write universal data loading script.  Some of my users use Spark, some Scalding, and who knows what will be next.  I want my users to be able to use a generic loading script that might return a RichPipe, RDD, or some other data format depending on the framework they are using, but I don't want to throw type safety completely out the window.

Comment: See [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/?_ga=1.8468725.1939486482.1433104516#scala.util.Either$)

Comment: Miles Sabin developed a method to implement union types using pure Scala in 2011 and which is revealed at http://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/.  For several years Odersky has been working on a new type system called the Dependent Object Types Calculus that incorporates union types and his work on that is described in http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~amin/dot/fool.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/?_ga=1.8468725.1939486482.1433104516#scala.util.Either%24) type provided by the Scala Library.

```
def myFunc(input:String): Either[Int, String] = {
    if (...) 
        Left(42) // return an Int
    else
        Right("Hello, world") // return a String
}
```

You can use more than two types by nesting, for instance `Either[A,Either[B,C]]`.

Comment: If  I nest them for multiple types, how do I refer to the nested structure?  By nesting the Left/Rights accordingly like Right(Left(42))?

Answer (score 1):

As already noted in comments you'd better use Either for this task, but if you really want it, you can use implicits

```
  object IntOrString {
    implicit def fromInt(i: Int): IntOrString = new IntOrString(None, Some(i))
    implicit def fromString(s: String): IntOrString = new IntOrString(Some(s), None)
  }
  case class IntOrString(str: Option[String], int: Option[Int])
  implicit def IntOrStringToInt(v: IntOrString): Int = v.int.get
  implicit def IntOrStringToStr(v: IntOrString): String = v.str.get

  def myFunc(input:String): IntOrString = {
    if(input.isEmpty) {
      1
    }  else {
      "test"
    }
  }

  val i: Int = myFunc("")
  val s: String = myFunc("123")
  //exception
  val ex: Int = myFunc("123")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make the typing by the user less implicit and more explicit.  Here are three  examples:

```
def loadInt(input: String): Int = { ... }

def loadString(input: String): String = { ... }
```

That's nice and simple.  Alternatively, we can have a function that returns the appropriate curried function using an implicit context:

```
def loader[T]()(implicit context: String): String => T = {
  context match {
    case "RDD" => loadInt _ // or loadString _
  }
}
```

Then the user would:

```
implicit val context: String = "RDD" // simple example
val loader: String => Int = loader()
loader(input)
```

Alternatively, can turn it into an explicit parameter:

```
val loader: String => Int = loader("RDD")
```

Comment: How is this awesome and elegant answer not upvoted?!